# Retrieve Instance names on scale sets using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have a ARM template which creates two scale sets, I need to retrieve the instance names from scale set 1 and use them as parameters in scale set 2 custom linux script extension. Is there a way to get the names only the fly when we are deploying the resources ?. I Have a powershell script which does the same. But I want my deployment to be using only ARM template , because we are creating the entire solution as a Managed app.

Comment: you need names or ip addresses?

Comment: either one would work for me. I need to run some Linux commands using names/IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

To reference first VM ip address use the following snippet:

```
"[reference('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/vmssName/virtualMachines/1/networkInterfaces/nicName/ipConfigurations/ipConfigurationName').ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]"
```

If you need all of those (ip from each vm in vmss) you could créate those values on the fly, you would most likely need a nested template to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. If you have any sample templates in regards to this scenario can you share it ?

Comment: only [this](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/vmss-custom-script.json), sorry